# Verifying child elements under a specific class in Selenium Web Driver (Code in C#)

Tags: c#, selenium

I have an Options field in my website where there are two child options. One is Change Password and other is Logout. I want to verify whether this two options are available there in a sequential order. Which mean the first option should be Change Password and the second option should be Logout. Here is the HTML of that portion:

```
<div class="user-options-container">
<div class="user-options-header">OPTIONS</div>
<div class="user-options">
<div class="user-options-item" action="changepwd">Change Password</div>
<div class="user-options-item" action="logout">Logout</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that? What I know is I can get them creating a list of IWebElement class and then verify those elements. But, getting confused on how to do that. I am using Selenium Web Driver 2 and C# as my language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving a quick solution on Java. But similar apis should be there in C#.

How about doing like this. For the HTML:

```
<div class="user-options-item" action="changepwd">Change Password</div>
<div class="user-options-item" action="logout">Logout</div>
```

get both the WebElement like this:

```
 List<WebElement> elements =  driver.findByElements(By.class("user-options-item"))
```

then you can get the text of element like:

```
elements.get(0).getText() //Change Password
elements.get(1).getText() //Logout
```

And check their orders. This should work for the given code, but if the same class is shared for other elements too, then the order will change.

Comment: I used the IWebElement to get the child options and found that they are giving Count = 2; which means there are 2 options available. But I can't verify their positions in no means !! Actually my Purpose is to see whether in the first option there is Change Password field and in the second option there is Logout Field.

Comment: As the elements.get(0) is not available for C# I tried with elements[0].Text 
But this gives no output. Just a blank in the Console(I tried to print that in the console)

Comment: @Rasam: Ya I mentioned right, class can be used for many elements in HTML. Probably element 1st is not `Change Password` in your case. Your testing against the public site? Can you share me the link?

Comment: Ok at long last I did solve the problem. Actually that option was enable when I mouse over on it. That's why it was giving no Text output. I worked with Actions class which pretty easily solve the problem. Thanks for the help !
And working on a project hosted in my computer. Not a public site actually.